# caustics cause way to high render time

Tags: rendering, caustics

I'm working on an archiviz scene, multiflat house with a little garden.
In the garden, I'm adding a small pool, created in a separate file and then imported in this.
During the pool creation, I played a little to set up caustics and I got a pretty good result, done in 5 minutes render in fullhd.

Now, in this scene, if caustics are activated, render time, from 10/12 minutes, render time goes up to 20-40 hours.

Is there any known bug by a chance?

Lorenzo

Comment: They're just very calculation heavy in an unbiased path tracer

Comment: i guess the issue here is that you have a much more complex scene between your lone pool and your full house with garden. If Blender tries to do caustics everywhere,that explains it. Maybe try to isolate your pool in a layer or even a scene and enable caustics only on that layer/scene and assemble everything in comp.